# Edit JomSocial Joomla Registration Page & Adding Content

Tags: joomla, jomsocial

I'm running JomSocial 3.2 on Joomla 3.
I want to add some content to the right side of the registration page.

Some pictures and other contents.
So far, i've been able to get to the "register.index.php" file,
which is the file that displays some of the content in the homepag.
The file is in: "/site_root/components/com_community/templates/default/" folder
but i've not been able to fully edit the whole registration page.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Joomla extensions, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in many different ways - even without editing any file. Install this extension: http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/advanced-module-manager and when editing module you'll have additional tab called "tasks" There will be field URL, type inside URLs of your registration form. Thanks to this you'll be able to assign modules to registration form.

You could also override for:

ROOT/components/com_community/templates/default/register.index.php

Copy it to:

ROOT/templates/your-template/html/com_community (if you don't have "html" or "com_community" folders, feel free to create them)

Then you may create module position inside file using this code:

```
$modules = JModuleHelper::getModules( 'reg-positon' );
foreach ($modules as $module) {
$_options = array( 'style' => 'xhtml' );
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule( $module, $_options );
}
```

Above code creates module position: "reg-positon'. You'll need to type this name manually as it will be not listed on module positions list.

Now you'll need a bit of html to display it on right or left of registration form.